# How to pass and interpolate Mixins within the "Rest Arguments" of another Mixin?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to make a Mixin ('proj') that includes an arbitrary number of another mixin ('image', 'youtubeClip', 'vimeoClip' etc...), as part of the proj mixin's Rest Arguments.

I'm not sure how close I am, if I should be using Blocks, or if this is even possible, but are there just interpolation characters that I need to apply so that the 'img' mixin is treated correctly?

Here is the full proj mixin:

```
mixin proj(date=`051819`, name=`Project Name`, desc=`A Project Description`, linkURL, linkText, longText=`Lorem dolor, Mr. Dolemite ipsum.`, fgColor=`#ff0072`, bgColor=`#333`, ...items)
  - var projectIDString = "project-" + date;
  - var projectRevealString = "reveal-" + date;
  div(id=projectIDString, class=`projectContainer`)
    div.left
      h3.date= date
    div.right
      h3.projectTitle(data-fg=fgColor data-bg=bgColor)= name
      p.description= desc
      div(id=projectRevealString class="reveal hiddenView colorway-bg")
        div.projectButtons(class="buttongroup shownView")
          div.closeButton(class="colorway-bg colorway-type colorway-border" data-target-id="studioInfoContainer") pX
          div.infoButton(class="colorway-bg colorway-type colorway-border" data-target-id="studioInfoContainer") p?
        div.imageCollection
          each item in items
            p!= item
        div.projectDescriptionView(class="hiddenView colorway-bg colorway-type colorway-border")
          div.projectInfoButtons(class="buttongroup")
            div.closeButton(class="colorway-bg colorway-type colorway-border" data-target-id="studioInfoContainer") piX
          p.links
            a(class="colorway-bg colorway-type colorway-border" href=linkURL target="_blank")= linkText
          div.longDescText(class="colorway-bg colorway-type colorway-border")!= longText
```

And here is a proj being created

```
+proj(`052218`,
  `PROJECT TITLE HERE`,
  `PROJECT SUBTITLE HERE`,
  `http://sensorymeditation.com`,
  `sensorymeditation.com`,
  `
    <p>Full length project description here...</p>
  `,
  `#706D6A`,
  `#2D2C2A`,
  `image(2, 2, 2, "non/01_USING_THE_APP.gif")`,
  `image(2, 2, 2, "non/01_USING_THE_APP.gif")`,
  `image(2, 2, 2, "non/01_USING_THE_APP.gif")`
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that won't modify your `proj` mixin a lot is to use mixins composition.

```
mixin bar(text)
   p= text

mixin foo(mixinName, arg)
   +#{mixinName}(arg)

+foo('bar', '2')
```

will call the `bar` mixin with '2' as first argument. **The reference to the mixin must be it's name as string.** Thus `+foo(bar, '2')` will fail.

You can even call multiple different mixins like the following example:

```
mixin A(text)
    a= text

mixin B(text)
    a(href='/')= text

mixin meta(heading, something, mixins, args)
    h1= heading
    p= something
    each mixin, index in mixins
        +#{mixin}(args[index])

html
    +meta('Hello', "let's try", ['A','B'], ['this', 'or that'])
```

will produce

```html
<html>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>let's try</p><a>this</a><a href="/">or that</a>
</html>
```

To conclude, you can modify your code like so :

```
mixin proj(yourInitialArgs..., bgColor=`#333`, items, itemsArgs)
   ...
   div.imageCollection
       each item, index in items
           +#{item}(...itemsArgs[index])
   ...

+proj(yourArgs..., `#2D2C2A`,
  ['image','image,'image'],
  [[2,2,2,"something"],[2,2,2,"something"],[2,2,2,"something"]]
  )
```

**Source:** https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2882#issuecomment-334998407